# Is Automated UI testing on watchOS possible

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-2

Automated UI testing/Unit testing is not a myth in iOS but can automated UI testing be done on the watchOS?? Any new feature with watchOS 2 or Xcode 7 that I missed. I looked into the profiler but I could not figure out how to automate testing on watch OS.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I've been trying to automate watchOS 2 apps but can't seem to select them as a target for UI Testing. I've tried using UIAutomation and only got to launch the app but nothing else. On watchOS 1, I actually got some automation working using UIA. However, it was never reliable. I was hoping UI Testing will fix this problem but it doesn't seem to support the apps.

Answer (score 3):

Since the beginning of watch apps, from WatchOS 1 on, there have been no test targets for watch apps. Nothing has changed with the launch of WatchOS 3: there are still no tests! Still, there are ways where we can perform the test Using **PivotalCoreKit to Test Watch Apps**

Please refer to the link below where author has explained it in detail. https://academy.realm.io/posts/cmduconf-boris-bugling-how-test-watch-apps/